# 一部のタグを非表示にしたり、上手に検索したりする方法

Tags: サポート, タグ, 検索

過去の討議見ようとしたのですが[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)のタグが少し多い気がします。

> 機能要望が実装された、バグが修正された、またはその他のリクエストの処理が完了したことを示す。

タグの説明にはこうありますが更新履歴として残しているのですか

[バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0)[翻訳](/questions/tagged/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3)[機能の要求](/questions/tagged/%e6%a9%9f%e8%83%bd%e3%81%ae%e8%a6%81%e6%b1%82)

この3つでは確かに、更新履歴はあったほうがいいですが投稿すべてが残っている必要はないと思います。

ですが、必要がゆえに残っている負担が増えるなどサイト側のデメリットもわかるので、今ある機能で[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)を非表示にしたり検索結果から除外するなどスタックオーバフローで通用するそういった機能はありませんか

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 特定のタグを非表示にする

ご自身のユーザーページから設定タブを開くと、「無視するタグ」という項目があると思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここでお好みのタグを指定していただいた上で、「無視するタグが付いた質問を非表示」を選択すれば、そのタグがついた質問は一覧に表示されなくなります（そのタグを指定して検索した場合を除く）。

### 特定のタグを除外して検索

`[タグ名]` と指定できるように、これを除外するにはマイナスを付けて `-[タグ名]` とします。

例えば、[`[機能の要求] -[status-completed]`](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E3%81%AE%E8%A6%81%E6%B1%82+-status-completed) などでしょうか。

---

検索結果の右側にある「高度な検索のヒント」というリンクをクリックすると、このような検索条件の書き方を見ることができます。また、[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)にも詳細な説明があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]